# Realm 0.87.5 in Android

Tags: java, android, mobile, realm

I've updated Realm to 0.87.5 and now I'm getting this error on build. Can you guys please help me with this?

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'. > 

com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK lib/x86/librealm-jni.so 

File1: /Users/[USER_NAME]/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.realm/realm-android/0.87.5/ab4e1fead1380252dad0e95658e53ea0c113e89c/realm-android-0.87.5.jar


File2: /Users/[USER_NAME]/.android/build-cache/97d752c34cee76117e22adcee3a9c2d132f80273/output/jni
```

Root Dependency:

[image: Root Dependency]

App Module Dependency:

[image: App Module Dependency]

Comment: Have you tried to clean your project and rebuild the project ?

Comment: Yes, and I also invalidated caches and restarted AS. But I'm still getting this issue..

Comment: Try with :
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.6.0-SNAPSHOT"
in your gradle project

Comment: Found the solution, I added it in root and module as well .. removed from the module and its fixed now..

Comment: Can you accept this as a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the project level gradle file

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.3.3"
```

And do this in your module level gradle file

```
 apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' // if using kotlin
 apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

But more importantly, make sure you don't have obsolete versions like 0.87.5 in your module level dependencies if you are trying to use a version newer than 0.88.0, such as 4.3.3 in this case.

```
 dependencies {
       // compile "io.realm:realm-android:0.87.5"  <-- make sure you don't have that
```

Then you might need to clean + rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.6.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

in your gradle project dependencies

and check if you're using :

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

in your Module app file

Answer (score 0):

Simply you don't have to compile any dependency for Realm DB, you just have to add two lines,

In your Gradle file at app level

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

In your Gradle file at project level

```
dependencies {
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.5.0"
}
```